# How to get appsettings value in ConfigureAppConfiguration c#

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-3.0

I have to set a configurable value in CreateHostBuilder either from appsettings or any way; I just tried using appsettings

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        {
                            var url = _configuration.GetSection("url");
                            config.SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).AddOcelot(// Set url here)

                               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                        });

                    });
```

But url value always returns as null.
Does anyone has better solution to get appsetings in ConfigureAppConfiguration or any better idea to use any other idea to set configuration value?

Comment: I am wonderig where _configuration from? and what you need url for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change like below:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var settings = config.Build();
            var url = settings.GetSection("url").Value;

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
             .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
             {
                 IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                  var url = configuration.GetSection("url");
             });
```

Comment: hey thanks but I have to get that Iconfiguration in configureAppConfiguration()